# LinkedIn Android SDK - deprecated? (last release 2015)

Tags: android, sdk, linkedin-api

**the last Release of LinkedIn Android SDK (1.1.4) was Nov 2015:**

https://developer.linkedin.com/downloads#androidsdk

For example it uses compile statements in its build.gradle file - Android Studio at buildtime instantly tells me:

"WARNING: Configuration 'compile' is obsolete and has been replaced with 'implementation' and 'api'.
It will be removed at the end of 2018. For more information see: http://d.android.com/r/tools/update-dependency-configurations.html"

Also this prevents programmers to upgrade apps using that old SDK with that old buildTools etc.

**Did I miss something?

Is a big web company like LinkedIn really that far behind?

Maybe now everything has to be done via Rest API´s or something like that?**

Thanks everyone for their time :)